# Model fit never finishes first epoch when using ImageDataGenerator

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tf.keras

I'm trying to recreate this jupyter notebook in a docker (configuration below): https://www.kaggle.com/ginsaputra/visual-inspection-of-casting-products-using-cnn (training a CNN classifier on 300x300 images) and am encountering weird problems.

Using the same methodology and data as in the notebook, I create a dataset using `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` and `.flow_from_directory` with a batch size of 32. This outputs (correctly): `Found 5307 images belonging to 2 classes`, so this works fine.

Firstly, when I run `model.fit` with 10 epochs, unlike the notebook which outputs `i/166 -`  during training, mine outputs `i/Unknown`. I read elsewhere that this is "correct" in that the dataset is being streamed from disk and it doesn't know the full size of the dataset yet until the first epoch is finished. Fair enough, but weird in that a) it works in the linked notebook and b), when creating the dataset it outputs `Found 5307 images...`, so it seems to be aware of its size, but okay. A minor annoyance I can live with.

However, given the batch size and size of the dataset, an epoch should be finished after 166 steps. That's not what's happening. The epoch doesn't finish after 166 steps, it just continues seemingly forever. The step number keeps increasing well into the five-digits-range, well past what the dataset has to offer, loss keeps going down, accuracy keeps going up...?

So I figured, I just pass an explicit `steps_per_epoch`-value of 166. Now things are even weirder: The number of steps goes up to 166 and then... nothing. Output just stops. Looking at `top`, no noticable changes in CPU or RAM usages (around 700% and 4% respectively, which makes sense since I'm not using CUDA). It's as if the model just keeps training, it just doesn't output anything to the shell.

Anyone any ideas of what's going on here?

Docker-configuration:

```
# See here for image contents: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/v0.177.0/containers/ubuntu/.devcontainer/base.Dockerfile

# [Choice] Ubuntu version: bionic, focal
ARG VARIANT="focal"
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/base:0-${VARIANT}

 RUN apt-get update && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
     && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends \
        python3.9 \
        python3-pip

RUN pip3 install \
    graphviz==0.16 \
    ipywidgets==7.5.1 \
    keras==2.4.3 \
    lime==0.2.0.1 \
    matplotlib==3.3.4 \
    numpy==1.19.2 \
    opencv-python-headless==4.5.1.48 \
    pyswip==0.2.10 \
    scikit-image==0.18.1 \
    tensorflow==2.5.0 \
    webcolors==1.11.1
```

Answer (score 0):

urgh, turns out, this was caused by a wrong `import` statement that caused a  confusion between `keras` and `tensorflow.keras`. Replacing `import keras...` by `import tensorflow.keras...` solved it.